# A shop sells 6 different kinds of donuts (and has at least 12 of each kind), how many different selections of 12...

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

A shop sells 6 different kinds of donuts (and has at least 12 of each kind).

1. How many different selections of 12 can be made?

**12 + 6 - 1

12**

Correct?

2. Suppose that chocolate is one kind of donuts sold. How many different selections of 12 donuts can be made if you have exactly 3 chocolate and at least one of each of the other kinds?

Not sure how to solve this.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The second is similar to the first.  having chosen $3$ chocolates you now must choose $9$ from the other five types.  That's easy to count.

Answer (score 1):

The first is correct but you would usually write the lower number as $6-1=5$.  Presumably you want some parentheses around the two lines to make ${12+6-1 \choose 12}$.  The lower number should be $6-1$ because you have $5$ dividers between the donut types.  As ${12+6-1 \choose 12}={12+6-1 \choose 5}$ it works.  For two, you need nine donuts of five types, with each type being represented at least once.  The stars and bars formula handles this.  You don't add the number of types in because the dividers are already separated.

Comment: Sorry about the formatting! For #1, I thought that  it is 12 combinations of a multiset with 6 types of objects and infinite repetition, no?

Comment: Yes it is, but you are placing dividers to make $12$  bins, so it takes $11$ dividers.  See [Wikipedia on stars and bars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)).  It answers the second part, too

Comment: Ok. I will review #1. For #2, would it be 70?

Comment: It seem like you'd place $5$ dividers to make $6$ bins in first part since $6$ types of donuts.

Comment: @Ned:  you are right.  I confused myself.  Fixed.

Comment: Got the first part, thank you.

Comment: Upper: 5 + 4 - 1. Lower: 4

Comment: Doesn't $\binom{12+6-1}{12}=\binom{12+6-1}{6-1}$?

Comment: @JMP they are equal, I just found that out